# Getting rid of blank html tr with empty tds in the rows

Tags: html, html-table

How could I go about dynamically handling a case like this so that they are gone or there is no space so that they appear gone ?

```
</tr><tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr><tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr><tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with jQuery like this:

```
  $('tr').filter(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    return (!$.trim($this.text()).length);
  }).remove();
```

This will remove `<tr>` that has all empty `<td>`

If you want to remove all empty `<td>` then just target it instead of `tr`

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/wuh7cwya/, I set it on button click.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work with my .aspx page unfortunately. Thanks for the correct answer in that.

Comment: If you implemented it correctly it should work no matter what server side technology you use. Maybe you could share your page source code.

Comment: I cannot exactly share source code but its more just a table with listboxes and checkboxes then empty rows with a bunch of empty table deliminators in some conditions. I even tried it as a button event to see.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with example table?

Comment: </tr><tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><span id="Label1">Label</span></td><td><select

Comment: Basically just making some object invisible in some circumstances and I can't rearrange the table enough to hide them and have others appear in their place...so then it looks like that..

Comment: Sorry but you should explain better what you actually need. This code is almost same like in question and solution in my answer removes emty rows in this case also. Like I said can you make jsfiddle with current table and then another with expected results.

Comment: is there a way to just do it on load or does there have to be a button.

Comment: Weird it just doesn't do anything  to the table.... I even put an ID to the table and referenced it...

Comment: I can't help you if I don't see your code.. check if there are some errors in console, experiment with code etc.

Comment: I do have a question, does that code just execute once ?

Comment: Yes, once on page load

Comment: Ok that must be the issue I need to learn how to execute it from the backend then I guess thank you.

Comment: tho I think it shoulda worked on the onclick as well

Comment: yes it should.. you have example on click in jsfiddle in my answer

Comment: I know I just can't figure out why the aspx page is doing this. and yes I used the same code with your button.